# Opening new tab and scrolling to ID isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hyperlink

I am using React Router's HashLink component, though I'm not sure that's relevant.

I have a page `books/detail/12345`. On this page I have a `<div id='availability-section'>`

If I click any links that navigate to this page and ID (`href=...books/detail/12345#availability-section`) with `target='_self'` it works just fine.

**The issue is:**

1. When `target='_blank'` the new tab never scrolls down to the `availability-section` div.
2. Furthermore, and the more frustrating part: I have a section on my page that shows related books, and each of those books has a link to its own detail page... If I'm on `books/detail/12345` and I click one of those links `<a href='...books/detail/54321#availability-section' target='_blank'>Book 54321</a>` it'll open a new tab, not scroll to the `#availability-section` and if I click over to the original tab... **it scrolled to the availability section**

I am at a loss for why this is happening. It's happening on chrome/ff/safari/edge (I don't test any others)

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it without react-router

At Book component in did mount event you should check link's hash, if it contains availability-section you should scroll to this element

**BookComponent**

```
componentDidMount(){
  if(window.location.hash.includes('availability-section')){
    const availabilitySectionNode = document.getElementById('availability-section')

    availabilitySectionNode 
    && availabilitySectionNode.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
}
```

or with hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (window.location.hash.includes('availability-section')) {
    const availabilitySectionNode = document.getElementById('availability-section')

    availabilitySectionNode
    && availabilitySectionNode.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
}, [])
```